How to write data in an Iceberg table from an AWS Glue Job
I have created a job in AWS Glue that is taking the data from a Postrgres table and writing it into a CSV file in S3. And is working fine.
The next step was to replace the target with a Iceberg table previously created in the databases/tables.
Here I am receiving an error: "Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; An error occurred while calling o125.pyWriteDataFrame. Unable to execute HTTP request: connect timed out".
I found some articles about running the job in a VPC instead of a public one. I did it but the error is the same.
Could you please tell me what should I do to solve the error in order to be able insert the data into the Iceberg table?
I tried to add all the possible permissions into the VPC, network connection, submask, etc., but not sure what exactly should I do.
Any suggestion or idea is welcomed :)
Thanks

When you run a job in a VPC by attaching a connection on the Job, using the write_data_frame.from_catalog() function, you generally need to provide Glue to be able to connect to the Glue endpoint glue.<region>.amazonaws.com in the private subnet.
Hence to resolve your issue, you would need to attach a Glue VPC endpoint (just like an S3 VPC endpoint) in your subnet, so that your subnet has access to fetch the Glue catalog (performs a Glue GetTable API call)
However, this works for writing into S3-CSV even though you use the same from_catalog() function without any need for a Glue endpoint is because AWS Glue uses some internal proxies to connect to some Glue assets for convenience only; that purely Glue libraries can use but cannot be accessed explicitly. It is always advised to add the endpoints to be on a safer side.
Although, why only Iceberg table was not able to access the Glue endpoint through this proxy could be due to the fact that there are special spark configurations involved such as:
--conf spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.catalog-impl=org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog --conf spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.io-…….

especially for Iceberg format which may interact differently with the Glue catalog and not be aware of the Glue proxies. And since this has a slightly different implementation, it failed with a Network timeout accessing the Glue endpoint.
If you are still facing an issue, consider raising a case with AWS Premium Support or post on AWS:RePost
